# Register to AWS Chime Meeting notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am trying to register Chime meeting event to a SNS topic, but I am not getting any message on the topic subscription. I am not very familiar with SNS and I am not sure how to debug.

I am using nodejs library (aws-sdk@^2.656.0) to create the meeting with the following configuration:

```
{
  "ExternalMeetingId":"meeting1587397186860",
  "ClientRequestToken":"<TOKEN>,
  "MediaRegion":"eu-central-1",
  "NotificationsConfiguration": {
      "SnsTopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:<ID>:<topic>"
  }
}
```

```
import { Chime, Endpoint } from 'aws-sdk';
const chime = new Chime({ region: 'us-east-1', accessKeyId: accessKey, secretAccessKey: secretKey });
chime.endpoint = new Endpoint('https://service.chime.aws.amazon.com/console');
chime.createMeeting(meetingConfiguration).promise().then(()=>{
...
});
...
```

The meeting is created without any error, but I do not get any notification on the SNS topic for any event. I also tried to set the topic as public and tried to publish message to it from AWS cli, and it worked.

Comment: we're seing this exact same problem :( we tried SNS, SQS, EventBridge, but no event ever arrives to them... did you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: it currently only works if your SNS/SQS/Eventbrige is on `us-east-1`. Not documented anywhere...

Comment: Hi @rubenfonseca / @Simone_Bracaloni : Did it resolved? I've configured SQS in `us-east-1` Still I'm not getting any message/event in this SQS. Pls help if I'm missing something.

Comment: Same problem for me. Did you found any solution ? Best